# Join array containing multiple user IDs with users table and create new array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an array that contains a bunch of user ids:

```
array('1,2,3,4')
```

And I need to match these user IDs to the id column in the users table and create arrays that have the first_name and last_name of the users in it. I know LEFT JOIN is probably what I have to use, but I can't figure out how to loop it. I tried foreach a while ago (sorry, deleted the code), but couldn't get it to work. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mysqli extension**. Try this code:

```
$userIds = array(1,2,3,4);
$users = array();
con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id in ('".implode(',',$userIds)."')");
$count=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $users[$count]['FirstName'] = $row['FirstName'];
  $users[$count]['LastName'] = $row['LastName'];
  $count++;
}

print_r($users);//result
```

Comment: I made a few modifications to this code, but this definitely put me right where I needed to be. I changed the while loop to this and echoed the result: while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
         $multiple_row_result[] = $row;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$arr = array('1,2,3,4');
$result = array();
$results = mysql_query("SELECT id,first_name,last_name FROM table_name WHERE id IN (".$arr.")");
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
       $result[] = $row;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I got: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given